# deprecated in iOS 9, compatibility?

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility, deprecated

I've upgraded my Xcode project with Xcode 7. I'm using `Objective-C`.
When I'm targeting `iOS 9.0` in deployment target, I've 36 warnings :

1. `UIAlertView` is deprecated, use `UIAlertController`.
2. `ABAddressBookRef` is deprecated, use `CNContactStore` ...
3. `setStatusBarStyle:animated` is deprecated, use `[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]`

and some other...
Well, I would like to keep compatibility with `iOS 9` and at least `iOS 8`.

Do I have to disregard these warnings for keeping compatibility with different OS ?

If I use `UIAlertController` iOS 8, is it working ?

What the best thing I've to do ? Using deprecated or replace with new code ?

Comment: Set your deployment target back to iOS 7.0 and you'll be fine (the messages will go away). Just make sure you conditionally use iOS 8 or 9 APIs so it doesn't crash on iOS 7.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for reply ! So if I'm targeting iOS 8 and iOS 9, if I use UIAlertController, does the code will work on both ?

Comment: Yes since `UIAlertController` was added in IOS 8.

Comment: FYI - you need to read the "SDK Compatibility Guide" in the iOS docs.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, but CNContactStore was introduced in iOS 9, so do you know if it will work with iOS 8 ?

Comment: Absolutely not. You can't use an API on a version of iOS from before it existed. Again, read the guide I mentioned.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks I will read the SDK Compatibility Guide. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deprecated" means at least one of the following:

- This API isn't gone yet, but it might be in the future, or on future platforms/technologies. For example, all API deprecated before iOS 8 is unavailable in Swift.
- There's a better alternative to this API, and the old one might not keep doing everything you need as the platform changes. For example, AssetsLibrary is still around even though it's deprecated, but it doesn't provide access to iCloud Photos or Live Photos — for those you need its replacement the Photos framework.

Those are things to consider *when targeting an OS version where the API are deprecated*.

However, *deprecation warnings are based on your project's minimum deployment target.* If you tell Xcode that you want to build for iOS 7 and newer, you won't see warnings for APIs that are deprecated as of iOS 8 or iOS 9.

If you want to deploy back to an older minimum OS target, but use features from a newer OS, you need to put availability checks in your code that uses the newer features. See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6) on compatibility/availability and weak linking in general, and/or [Checking API Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID523) for Swift.

Comment: Nice answer ! :) Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

If you are no longer targeting the older versions of iOS then its recommended to update deprecated code. You don't absolutely have to though, deprecated methods are still officially supported in Apple's SDKs, but one day Apple may remove those methods.

Here's what Apple says about deprecation:

> From time to time, Apple adds deprecation macros to APIs to indicate
>   that those APIs should no longer be used in active development. When a
>   deprecation occurs, it is not an immediate end-of-life to the
>   specified API. Instead, it is the beginning of a grace period for
>   transitioning off that API and onto newer and more modern
>   replacements. Deprecated APIs typically remain present and usable in
>   the system for a reasonable amount of time past the release in which
>   they were deprecated. However, active development on them ceases and
>   the APIs receive only minor changes—to accommodate security patches or
>   to fix other critical bugs. Deprecated APIs may be removed entirely
>   from a future version of the operating system.
>
> As a developer, it is important that you avoid using deprecated APIs
>   in your code as soon as possible. **At a minimum, new code you write
>   should never use deprecated APIs. And if you have existing code that
>   uses deprecated APIs, update that code as soon as possible.**
>   Fortunately, the compiler generates warnings whenever it spots the use
>   of a deprecated API in your code, and you can use those warnings to
>   track down and remove all references to those APIs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html